# ASCII Changing Numbers

Tags: python, ascii

I’m having a problem in my Python ASCII Code where when I am trying to convert a letter to ASCII it will convert the numbers from the ASCII into more ASCII code. How do I fix this?

```
Choice = input("Now tell us which code language you like to convert this to Binary or ASCII: \n")
Code = input("Insert your code here, it converts letters to Binary/ASCII: \n\n")

Zero = '048'
One = '049'
Two = '050'
Three = '051'
Four = '052'
Five = '053'
Six = '054'
Seven = '055'
Eight = '056'
Nine = '057'

NewCode = Code.replace('0', Zero)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('1', One)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('2', Two)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('3', Three)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('4', Four)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('5', Five)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('6', Six)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('7', Seven)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('8', Eight)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('9', Nine)
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Please give an example of the expected output. I am afraid you do not fully understand what ASCII is.

Comment: The problem is that one replacement will have impact on the second one. For example if the original string is `'0'`, then after the first replacement it is `'048'`, so if we then call `.replace('4', Four)`, it will result in `'00528'`.

Comment: Among other things, we need to know what you expected as output.  Your code appears to do what you told it: replace a single digit with three digits, all of them string characters.

Comment: Too easy (and probably too advanced for the OP) to add as an answer, but `print (''.join('%03d' % ord(x) for x in s))` works just fine. (Also not intended as a "fix" to OP's code.)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be accomplished in literally one line without hardcoding the ASCII codes of the characters:

```
code = '3210' # Do not use initial upper-case letters for variable names!
newCode = ''.join('{:03}'.format(ord(n)) for n in code)
# '051050049048'
```

However, the purpose of your exercise is still unclear. Also mind that '0XY' typically means that 'XY' is written in the octal number system. Therefore, neither X nor Y can be an 8 or a 9.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the replacement strings contain characters that will be replaced by later `.replace()` calls.

One solution is to process the input a character at a time, rather than using `.replace()` on the entire string.

BTW, Python has an `ord()` function that returns the code for a character, which is normally ASCII.

```
NewCode = ''
for char in Code:
    NewCode += str(ord(char)).zfill(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that you are constantly modifying `NewCode` so that at each step it continues to modify itself, changing the numbers to their ASCII numbers. Instead of re-using `NewCode` for each `replace`statement, use a new variable as a buffer.

```
Code = '3210'
NewCode = Code.replace('', Zero) #NewCode is now 321048
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
NewCode = NewCode.replace('4', Four) #The '4' near the end of '321048' gets replaced with '052' making NewCode = 32100528
print(NewCode, '\n\n')
time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Should `''` be `'0'`?

Comment: How does using a new variable solve the problem? The problem is that the replacements contain characters that later replacements will process.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it like this, it ensures you don't change the ascii code twice by using a buffer.

```
Code = raw_input("Insert your code here, it converts letters to Binary/ASCII: \n\n")

lst_words = ['Zero', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine']
lst_numbers = ['048','049','050','051','052','053','054','055','056','057']

for i in range(10):
    Code = Code.replace(str(i), lst_words[i])
print(Code)
for i in range(10):
    Code = Code.replace(lst_words[i], lst_numbers[i])
print(Code)
```